# Bash Script with IF statement that executes "gem" and checks result

Tags: ruby, bash, if-statement

I am trying to write a bash script that checks if a gem is installed.  If the gem is installed I will do option A.  If not, I will do option B.

To see if the gem is installed I use:

```
gem list -i "^gemname$"
```

This prints "true" or "false" to the screen.  I think it outputs the text "true" and "false" but I am not sure if itself has a return value.

The gem i am searching for is "xcpretty" and my script is:

```
if [[$(gem list -i "^xcpretty$") == true]]; then
    echo "Found XCPRETTY do other things"
else
    echo "Cant find XCPRetty do things"
fi
```

This fails with the error:
.xxxxx: line 1: [[false: command not found

Because the gem is not installed on my system, it returned "false".  But how do I compare what it returned with "false"?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I checked this one:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52800/how-to-do-an-if-statement-from-the-result-of-a-executed-command

But it doesn't quite match what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add space after `[[` and before `]]`.

```
[[ $(gem list -i "^xcpretty$") == true ]]
```